# Is there any linear algebra textbook presented using logical symbols?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, reference-request, quantifiers

I'm currently going through a book called Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, and to be honest, his book seems to be very loose with what things he defines. For instance , the symbol 0 could be mean a zero vector or a scalar.  Not only on defining things , but the proofs as well are also loose. I feel like this book is not meant for the beginner like myself who wants to jump into learning the theory behind linear algebra. It feels more like a book for reviewing or brushing upon your linear algebra skills.

In any case, I find that I learn best when doing proofs is to translate the statements in terms of quantifiers and connectives. In short, I don't want to go dissect all the flowery language. I just want to cut to the chase. So, are there any books that's presented in this manner that I described?

Comment: David Lay's book is pretty straightforward and geared towards beginners

Comment: Searle's book is like matrix algebra for business majors. Not heavy on the linear algebra theory at all, but very good connections with the real world [hence the term matrix algebra]. Quite 'to the chase' as you say. Definitely something to strengthen your foundations and then look at a book like Lay's or Streng's.

Comment: From page 8 of Linear Algebra Done Right (3rd edition): "Here we are using the symbol 0 in two different ways---on the left side of the equation in 1.14, the symbol 0 denotes a list of length $n$, whereas on the right side, each 0 denotes a number. This potentially confusing practice actually causes no problems because the context always makes clear what is intended." This practice of letting the symbol 0 serve multiple purposes is common in linear algebra. It is not an indication of being loose---the context makes the meaning clear. Using a different symbol for each use of 0 would be clumsy.